# jQuery - Attaching change event to input elemnt if doesn't exists already

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two parts in the code below.

> 1. For each form, Serialize the form and store the serialized value in data attribute of the form itself.
> 2. For each input element inside form, attach a change event, and then compare the form's serialized value on each change; and then
>      enable/disabled button accordingly.

The question is about 2nd part

How do i detect if "change" event is already attached to "input" element, and if it is, then do not attach the event again to that element?

```
module.trackFormChanges = function (formSelector) {
    $(formSelector)
        .each(function () {
            var theForm = $(this);
            theForm.data('serialized', theForm.serialize());
            var id = theForm.prop("id");
            $("button[form='" + id + "']").prop('disabled', true);
            isFormDirty = false;
        })
        .on('change input', function () {
            var theForm = $(this);
            isFormDirty = !(theForm.serialize() == theForm.data('serialized'));
            var id = theForm.prop("id");
            $("button[form='" + id + "']")
                .prop('disabled', !isFormDirty);
        })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use event bubbling and not worry about having to attach events?

Comment: Where is `change` event attached to `input` element ?

Comment: @guest271314 ".on('change input') will attach change event handler to all input elements

Comment: @user3862378 Perhaps not gather Question correctly ? _"How do i detect if "change" event is already attached to "input" element,"_ ? Not appear that `change` event is attached to `input` element at `js` at OP , but parent `form` element ? What is expected result ?

Comment: You both are correct, .on('change input') will attach change & input event handler to Form element not its children.  W3Schools  says "The on() method attaches one or more event handlers for the selected elements and child elements." http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_on.asp  however jQuery api says " Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements" http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my issue by refactoring as @kiranvj suggested

```
module.trackFormChanges = function (formSelector) {
    $(formSelector)
        .each(function () {
            var theForm = $(this);
            theForm.data('serialized', theForm.serialize());
            var id = theForm.prop("id");
            $("button[form='" + id + "']").prop('disabled', true);
            isFormDirty = false;

            var isEventHandlerAttached = theForm.data('eventattached');
            if (isEventHandlerAttached == undefined || isEventHandlerAttached == false) {
                theForm.data('eventattached', true);
                theForm.on('change input', function () {
                    var theForm = $(this);
                    isFormDirty = !(theForm.serialize() == theForm.data('serialized'));
                    var id = theForm.prop("id");
                    $("button[form='" + id + "']")
                        .prop('disabled', !isFormDirty);
                })
            }                
        })            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if change event is attached to an element like this

```
var foo = $.data( $('YOUR-SELECTOR-HERE').get(0), 'events' ).change
```

For your case I suggest you add a 'data-change' attribute to the inputs. Make it true when the event is attached during the first time and check for this attribute again when you try to attach event again. If this attribute is true, don't attach the event again.